# Semantic checking of protobuf generated JS code in VS Code and JSDoc

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, protocol-buffers, jsdoc

I am writing a Node.js application that is using Google Protocol Buffers to communicate with a C# client.

I am using the official Google's JavaScript compiler with CommonJS style imports. I have recently added linting to my project with eslint and specifically the default "google" config. VS Code offers semantic checking (setting ID `js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs`) which combined with JSDoc, that the google lint style enforces, works very well for introducing a little bit of type-safety into my application. Now the issue is that I can't get the VS Code semantic checking to work with Protocol Buffers generated JS code. The code runs fine so at least Node understands the protocol buffer code.

Here is a small example code, *index.js*, that's giving me trouble:

```
// Alteratively following works for JSDoc as well: /** @typedef { import('./bar').Bar } Bar */
const {Bar} = require('./bar');

// The typedef imports are not working:
// /** @typedef { import('./foo_pb').fooPackage } fooPackage */
// ^ Warns "Namespace ...foo_pb has no exported member fooPackage"
// /** @typedef { import('./foo_pb').Foo } Foo */
// ^ Warns "Namespace ...foo_pb has no exported member Foo"
const fooPackage = require('./foo_pb');

/**
 * @param {Bar} bar
 */
function useBar(bar) {
  bar.printHi();
}

// VS Code warns "Namespace <abspath>/foo_pb has no exported member 'Foo'."
/**
 * @param {fooPackage.Foo} foo
 */
function useFoo(foo) {
  console.log(foo);
}

useBar(new Bar());
// VS Code warns "Property 'Foo' does not exist on type 'typeof import("<abspath>/foo_pb")'."
useFoo(fooPackage.Foo.FOO_OK);
```

Here is the *foo.proto* file and it generated output *foo_pb.js*:

```
// foo.proto
syntax = "proto3";

package fooPackage;

enum Foo {
  FOO_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
  FOO_OK = 1;
}

// foo_pb.js
var jspb = require('google-protobuf');
var goog = jspb;
var global = Function('return this')();

goog.exportSymbol('proto.fooPackage.Foo', null, global);
/**
 * @enum {number}
 */
proto.fooPackage.Foo = {
  FOO_UNSPECIFIED: 0,
  FOO_OK: 1
};

goog.object.extend(exports, proto.fooPackage);
```

Here is *bar.js* used in the *index.js* that works as I would expect with the semantic checking:

```
/** A Bar class */
class Bar {
  /** Prints hi */
  printHi() {
    console.log('Hi');
  }
}

module.exports = {
  Bar,
};
```

Here is my, abridged, *package.json*:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "protoc --proto_path=./ --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./ foo.proto",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/eslint ./"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "google-protobuf": "^3.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

It's not clear to me whether this is issue with VS Code, the Google's protocol buffer code or JSDoc and how does TypeScript and Closure play into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonable solution for me to use following require syntax: `const Foo = require('./foo_pb').Foo;`.

VS Code semantic checking does NOT complain about it, but it does have following downsides:

- Each symbol must be imported separately while `const fooPackage = require('./foo_pb');` imports all symbols into `fooPackage` "namespace". This could be argued is actually a benefit since the whole "Include what you use" principle.
- VS Code is not able to inspect those symbols so auto-complete won't be working for them
- Linting might complain about `no-unused-vars` on those imports if they are, for example, just function parameters. A simple solution for me is to wrap those imports `/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */` blocks.

Just for reference, here is working *index.js*:

```
const {Bar} = require('./bar');

const Foo = require('./foo_pb').Foo;

/**
 * @param {Bar} bar
 */
function useBar(bar) {
  bar.printHi();
}

/**
 * @param {Foo} foo
 */
function useFoo(foo) {
  console.log(foo);
}

useBar(new Bar());
useFoo(Foo.FOO_OK);
```